# Scraping ptoblem HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ar.wikipedia.orghttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: python

so i have this problem. I'm trying to scrape some wiki pages, i start with one link and try to extract all the text from it, i save links into a List, and based on the wordcount of my final text, i'll start a new request withe links appended to the list. everytime i stry it says:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ar.wikipedia.orghttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: (url i'm working with)
I'm not sure about it i'm new to BeautifulSoup, can anyone help ?

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from time import sleep

def ScrapingLink(LinksList):
    FinalText = ""
    if len(word_tokenize(FinalText)) < 1000000:

        for Link in LinksList:

            url = "https://ar.wikipedia.org" + Link
            Response = requests.get(url)

            if Response.ok:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(Response.content)
                paragraphes = soup.find_all("p")

                for paragraphe in paragraphes:
                    FinalText = FinalText + paragraphe.text
                    for ref in paragraphe.find_all('a', href=True):
                        LinksList.append(ref['href'])

    return FinalText
```

Comment: are you sure `ar.wikipedia.orghttps` is a valid url?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ In code it seems seems to be valid https://ar.wikipedia.org

Comment: Which means, that the `Link` variable only contained a string `https`. Could that be possible?

Comment: no i tried printing it, that link is valid for arabic content in wikipedia, and the link variable contains a full link to an artical

Comment: i'm adding that portion bcz the link returned from that code are "/wiki/xxxxxx" and i need that in order to get a valid url